# If one rider on the white horse represent's "Christ," does the other rider on the white horse represent the "Anti-Christ"?

Tags: revelation

After reading this question  [Whose blood is on the white rider's robe?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11521/whose-blood-is-on-the-white-riders-robe) my attention was drawn to another white horse and rider that we read about in Revelation 6:2 (NIV),

> I looked, and there before me was a white horse! Its rider held a bow,
>   and he was given a crown, and he rode out as a conqueror bent on
>   conquest.

In the previous question,it was established that the rider on the white horse answers to Jesus Christ.One of the answers "highlights" this in the conclusion.

> In Revelation 19, Christ is pictured as already having started His
>   judgment upon the nations (which is why His robe is already dipped in
>   blood). Isaiah 63 answers the "where" and "how" His garments became
>   bloodied—in the judgment done in Edom. Then Joel 3 and Zech 14
>   prophesy of the same event as Rev 19, which is not in Edom, but near
>   Jerusalem in the Valley of Jehoshaphat, but is another winepress
>   trodding event during Christ's second coming.

When we view the two riders on the white horses,one will note that there is "striking similarities," (one being the crown that the rider receives at the start of his mission), but some believe that the rider in question answers to the "Anti-Christ," and others believe that he answers to Jesus Christ.

From the symbolism and scripture available to the reader, in relation to the rider on the white horse,how does one interpret this to reveal the true identity of this rider.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7752/the-four-horsemen-of-the-apocalypse)

Comment: Good Question Bagpipes. +1

Comment: The issue is that through out scripture, hunters are always preferred over Shepherds. Nimrod was a hunter so were Ishmael, Esau etc. But they were rejected and their Shepherd brothers were chosen instead (Isaac and jacob). As hunters, they foreshadowed their natural enmity with the Lamb of prophecy. The rider on the Whitehorse of Rev 6 uses a bow. So this makes him a hunter. Secondly, it is only his horse that is white, not his garment. So he rides upon a royal steed but his own clothing/character is not revealed. So these are likely hints about his being the Antichrist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question,

> *What one has to remember is the blood on the robe that the rider on
>   the white horse wears,is symbolic and the verse is to be interpreted
>   symbolically*(taken from [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11521/whose-blood-is-on-the-white-riders-robe))

Since what the rider wears is symbolic(or figurative-representitive of another reality), therefore the horse he rides on is also figurative.

Both riders ride on "White" horses; "white" is to be understood as the color of purity,

> **And one of the elders answered, saying unto me, What are these which
>   are arrayed in *white* robes? and whence came they?
>   14And I said unto him, Sir, thou knowest. And he said to me, These are
>   they which came out of great tribulation, and have washed their robes,
>   and made them *white* in the blood of the Lamb**

A "white" horse is a horse that carries truth which is pure. Since the "Antichrist" or Beast of Rev. 12:3 is red,

> **And there appeared another wonder in heaven; and behold a great *red*
>   dragon, having seven heads and ten horns, and seven crowns upon his
>   heads.**

It can be inferred that the "Beast" of Rev. 13:1 is also red(some translations use scarlet), since the only difference between the 2 Beasts is the placement of their crowns.

Therefore, it can be concluded that the 1st rider is **not** the Antichrist. Another passage which also supports this truth is from Isa. 1:18,

> **Come now, and let us reason together, saith the LORD: though your sins
>   be as scarlet, they shall be as *white* as snow; though they be *red* like
>   crimson, they shall be as wool.**

The question therefore becomes, "If it is not the Antichrist, then who is it"?

Sometime ago I recorded an answer to [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9147/who-is-being-described-in-rev-1311-12-and-in-what-context-do-we-understand-the) in which I quoted an author who described 4 different methods(or hermeneutics) of eschatological interpretation. Depending on which one you use, will depend on the answer(or non-answer) you have. I will discount both the Idealist and Preterist/Covenant Theology interpretation for this discussion, because neither remotely suggests the 1st rider as being the "Antichrist".

Dispensational eschatology has mostly been attributed as seeing the 1st rider as the "Antichrist". A main expositor for Dispensationalism writes,

> *“From what has already been plainly found, the time here is that of
>   the earliest stage of Antichrist’s times. It has been learned from 2
>   Thess. 2:7-8 that his open revelation succeeds the removal from the
>   earth of the restraining agency of the overcoming saints. And from
>   Dan. 7:8, 20; 8:9; and 11:40-43, it is made plain that Antichrist
>   first conducts in the earth a period of sweeping, victorious warfare.
>   The field of conflict will be the territories of the restored northern
>   (Syrian), southern (Egyptian), and eastern (Mesopotamian) kingdoms of
>   the old Grecian Empire. The figure of a white horse, and of his rider
>   seated erect with drawn bow and with victor’s wreath upon his brow, is
>   the favourite oriental symbol of the military conqueror” (taken from A
>   Revelation of Jesus Christ by John F. Walvoord)*

Dispensationalism MUST make this rider the "Antichrist" because it sees the church as being raptured after the last letter to the churches in Rev. 3,

> *After chapter 3 of the book of Revelation, the church is not
>   mentioned by the apostle John until Revelation 19:7-11. It is
>   important to understand the underlying reason for this. The most
>   reliable reason is that the church will be raptured to the Heaven
>   before the opening of the "Seven Seals" in Revelation 6. That is to
>   say, the church will not undergo the 7 years Tribulation Period. In
>   this connection, it is worthwhile to examine the reasons for the
>   church will not undergo the tribulation period before proceeding to
>   chapter 4 of the book of Revelation.
>   For more information in this topic, please read Dr. J. Dwight
>   Pentecost, Things to Come, A Study in Biblical Eschatology, Zondervan*

Dwight Pentecost is another major proponent of Dispensationalism.

To summerize Dispensationalism's view, the "white" horse cannot be 'truly white' since,
1) It is not Christ
2) It comes after the church is Raptured

This is because their hermeneutic forbids them any other consideration.

Another view is "Historicist", and basically states that eschatology 'historically' unfolds throughout the centuries. There is much disagreement as to what the various symbologies mean, so it is not the most popular; but I believe it is the most honest, as it doesn't 'bunch-up' all the interpretations of Revelations at the beginning of the church age, as Preterism/Covenant Theology does, nor does it 'bunch-up' all the interpretations of Revelations beyond Chapter 3 into the last 7 years, as Dispensationalism does. It sees significant prophetic fulfillment throughout church history, therefore the focus is not on "which end of the spectrum" but revelation-an unfolding of God's plan.

So to answer the question, "Who is the rider", let's examine the whole verse,

> **And I saw when the Lamb opened one of the seals, and I heard, as it
>   were the noise of thunder, one of the four beasts saying, Come and
>   see. 2And I saw, and behold a white horse: and he that sat on him had
>   a bow; and a crown was given unto him: and he went forth conquering,
>   and to conquer.**(Rev. 6:1-2)

The Lamb opens the seal, so it stands that the Lamb is not riding the horse-we see the Lamb(Word of God) in Rev. 19:11. But the "rider is riding a white horse", who is it?

Since it is figurative, it is representitive of another reality; the 'white horse' is a 'vehicle' for the righteous to ride on, and that 'vehicle' is the Gospel.

> **And this gospel of the kingdom shall be preached in all the world for
>   a witness unto all nations; and then shall the end come.**(Matt. 24:14)

The word "Witness",

> *'witness'μαρτύριον, μαρτυρίου, τό (μάρτυρ (cf. μάρτυς)), (from Pindar,
>   Herodotus down), the Sept. for עֵד, עֵדָה, more often for עֵדוּת (an
>   ordinance, precept); most frequently for מועֵד (an assembly), as
>   though that came from עוּד to testify, whereas it is from יָעַד to
>   appoint; testimony*(Thayer's Lexicon)

is a ordinance and testimony, by which the world is judged. Therefore, the gospel must go out, so that God's righteous judgements apply, or men would not know from what they are being judged. But who is the 'rider' and why does he have a 'bow' and why is a crown given to him?

When Constantine said,"In hoc signo vinces"(under this sign, conquer), this rider went forth, conquering, and to conquer. It 1st swept the Western European Nations, then throughout the whole earth(Asia, Africa, Mid-East, North America, South America) where governments 1st conquered, then sent forth missionaries to evangelize the people. Pres. McKinley said in 1903,

> *"When I next realized that the Philippines had dropped into our laps I
>   confess I did not know what to do with them. . . And one night late it
>   came to me this way. . .1) That we could not give them back to Spain-
>   that would be cowardly and dishonorable; 2) that we could not turn
>   them over to France and Germany-our commercial rivals in the
>   Orient-that would be bad business and discreditable; 3) that we not
>   leave them to themselves-they are unfit for self-government-and they
>   would soon have anarchy and misrule over there worse than Spain's
>   wars; and 4) that there was nothing left for us to do but to take them
>   all, and to educate the Filipinos, and uplift and civilize and
>   Christianize them, and by God's grace do the very best we could by
>   them, as our fellow-men for whom Christ also died*(from [here](http://historymatters.gmu.edu/blackboard/mckinley.html))

McKinley was only representitive of the previous world rulers, who saw it their duty to, "Christianize" the worlds they conquered, and rule until they did. Thus we see the 'bow' as an weapon of long distance sending, whereas the 'crown', of which ONLY this rider wears, denotes governance.

What is important to see is the rider didn't necessarily wear white(doesn't say what he wore). But HIS PURPOSE(the White Horse), was to "conquer" to enable the Gospel, and that purpose has been fuflfilled.

Comment: @Bagpipes You'll never guess who I robbed the 1st quote from ;>)

Comment: I would say you borrowed it.Proverbs 27:17

Comment: @Bagpipes Con su permiso?

Answer (score 1):

Peace.

He that sat on the white horse in Revelation 6:2 signifies those who come falsely in the name (authority) of the Lord, saying, “I am the Christ”…that is, I am the anointed (with the Spirit to preach the Word of God).

> Revelation 6:2 KJV (2)  *And I saw, and behold a white horse: and he
>   that sat on him had a bow; and a crown was given unto him: and he went
>   forth conquering, and to conquer.*

Matthew 24 shows us a parallel to Revelation 6.  The testimony of Jesus in Matthew is the spirit/breath of prophecy that we find in Revelation.

Men come forth to deceive us. They come forth and say “peace, peace” when what follows after them (the other horses) is not peace but the sword, famine, misery and destruction.  These deceitful men are used to destroy those who become forgetful in doing His will.

Destruction and misery are in their ways and the way of peace that do not know.   They want you to come join their churches where there is no peace and they easily seduce those who are forgetful to do His commands. Jesus warned us about them.

> Matthew 24:4-5 KJV (4)  **And Jesus answered and said unto them, Take
>   heed that no man deceive you.**

They are saying “I am the Christ”….I am the anointed with the Spirit.  Christ = anointed.

Yet,  they are really “antichrist”….that is, the instead-of-Christ….the instead –of-anointed.  They are not anointed with the Spirit to preach.    They are deceivers who say they are anointed with Spirit of God to preach to those who are deceived and are led astray by them.  The MANY antichrists are deceiving MANY as many receive them as truly sent of Christ.

> (5)  ***For many shall come in my name, saying, I am Christ; and shall
>   deceive many.***

The rider of the white horse has a bow (with no arrows).  They come in peace supposedly.  The false prophets says “peace, peace” when there is no peace if we are deceived into receiving them as our “king” (a crown was given the rider on the white horse).

Revelation 6 opens with the “noise of thunder”.

> Revelation 6:1 KJV (1)  *And I saw when the Lamb opened one of the
>   seals, and I heard, as it were the noise of thunder, one of the four
>   beasts saying, Come and see.*

The rider comes with a bow with no arrows (peace, peace) but the rider is really used to shoot the arrows of God who thunders from Heaven upon those who do not do His will.  The wrath of God is revealed from Heaven upon those who hold down the Truth in their unrighteousness. The judgment of God (the sword, famine, pestilence) is upon those who are led astray by false prophets in their forgetfulness in doing His will.

They use the same instruction of those who are truly sent by Christ by saying “peace” to us and yet they are falsely sent.

> Luke 10:5 KJV (5)  And into whatsoever house ye enter, **first say,
>   Peace be to this house**.

They easily deceive those who forget to always follow the “golden rule”.

> Matthew 7:12-15 KJV (12)  ***Therefore all things whatsoever ye would
>   that men should do to you, do ye even so to them: for this is the law
>   and the prophets.***

They come forth and lead many astray from the Way of righteousness and down the broad way that leads to destruction of their mortal bodies as many are perishing from off this earth.  The life of Jesus is not being made manifest in the mortal body of anyone that goes and sits together with them.

MANY go down that path as they follow their “leader”….their pastor whom they have received as their king (a crown is given to the rider on the white horse).

> (13)  *Enter ye in at the strait gate: for wide is the gate, and broad
>   is the way, that leadeth to destruction, **and many there be which go in
>   thereat:** (14)  Because strait is the gate, and narrow is the way,
>   which leadeth unto life, and few there be that find it.*

They are false prophets as they come forth and speak “peace, peace” when there is none for those who will follow after them.  They come posing as ministers of righteousness when they are not.

> (15)  ***Beware of false prophets,*** which come to you in sheep's clothing,
>   but inwardly they are ravening wolves.

False prophets predict “peace” to those who come and keep company with them.  They say “I will give you assured peace in this place” .... “you shall not see the sword, neither shall you have famine”….but these very things are what is in their midst if we keep company with those who are false prophets.  The judgment of God is already upon them and their followers.

> Jeremiah 14:13-15 KJV (13)  *Then said I, Ah, Lord GOD! **behold, the
>   prophets say unto them, Ye shall not see the sword, neither shall ye
>   have famine; but I will give you assured peace in this place**. (14) 
>   Then the LORD said unto me, The prophets prophesy lies in my name: I
>   sent them not, neither have I commanded them, neither spake unto them:
>   they prophesy unto you a false vision and divination, and a thing of
>   nought, and the deceit of their heart. (15)  Therefore thus saith the
>   LORD **concerning the prophets that prophesy in my name, and I sent them
>   not, yet they say, Sword and famine shall not be in this land; By
>   sword and famine shall those prophets be consumed***.

They come in their own name (authority) and many receive them supposedly in the name (authority) of the Lord.   If another shall come in his own name (authority), then him shall many receive.

> John 5:41-43 KJV (41)  *I receive not honour from men. (42)  But I know
>   you, that ye have not the love of God in you. (43)  I am come in my
>   Father's name, and ye receive me not: **if another shall come in his own
>   name, him ye will receive.***

Many gladly receive them as a “king” over them.  They gladly let these men exalt themselves over them and gladly let them bring them into bondage….where many are serving their church handwritings of church dogmas.

> 2 Corinthians 11:19-20 KJV (19)  *For ye suffer fools gladly, seeing ye
>   yourselves are wise. (20)  **For ye suffer, if a man bring you into
>   bondage, if a man devour you, if a man take of you, if a man exalt
>   himself, if a man smite you on the face**.*

The rider on the white horse was given a crown as people receive them as their “king” rather their servant.   They are preaching themselves in their own authority and come as kings rather than preaching Christ Jesus the Lord and being servants.

Christ Jesus is the King not them.  Those who serve the King are servants of everyone that they preach to and are not coming forth to be kings over them.

> 2 Corinthians 4:5 KJV (5)  **For we preach not ourselves, but Christ
>   Jesus the Lord; and ourselves your servants for Jesus' sake.**

Whosoever will be chief among you, let him be your servant. The Son of man did not come to be ministered unto but to minister.

> *Matthew 20:25-28 KJV (25)  But Jesus called them unto him, and said,
>   Ye know that the princes of the Gentiles exercise dominion over them,
>   and they that are great exercise authority upon them. (26)  But it
>   shall not be so among you: but whosoever will be great among you, let
>   him be your minister; (27)  **And whosoever will be chief among you, let
>   him be your servant: (28)  Even as the Son of man came not to be
>   ministered unto, but to minister,** and to give his life a ransom for
>   many.*

The “king” pastor that many choose to serve...to minister unto.. will reign over them and take of them and put them to work in his “ministry”.

> 1 Samuel 8:10-20 KJV (10)  **And Samuel told all the words of the LORD
>   unto the people that asked of him a king.**

The “king” pastor will exalt himself and take of you and put you to work in his "kingdom" so to speak.  He will put you to work in his own "ministry".

> (11)  And he said, **This will be the manner of the king that shall
>   reign over you:** He will take your sons, and appoint them for himself,
>   for his chariots, and to be his horsemen; and some shall run before
>   his chariots. (12)  And he will appoint him captains over thousands,
>   and captains over fifties; and will set them to ear his ground, and to
>   reap his harvest, and to make his instruments of war, and instruments
>   of his chariots. (13)  **And he will take** your daughters to be
>   confectionaries, and to be cooks, and to be bakers. (14)  A**nd he will
>   take** your fields, and your vineyards, and your oliveyards, even the
>   best of them, and give them to his servants. (15)  **And he will take**
>   the tenth of your seed, and of your vineyards, and give to his
>   officers, and to his servants. (16)  **And he will take** your
>   menservants, and your maidservants, and your goodliest young men, and
>   your asses, **and put them to his work.**

He will "take"...take....take.

Those who receive such shall be his (the king pastor’s) servants. He is not there to minister but to be ministered unto.

> *(17)  **He will take** the tenth of your sheep: a**nd ye shall be his
>   servants.** (18)  **And ye shall cry out in that day because of your king
>   which ye shall have chosen you; and the LORD will not hear you in that
>   day**.*

Yet, many want a king over them. They gladly put up with those who exalt themselves over them.

> (19)  *Nevertheless the people refused to obey the voice of Samuel; and
>   they said, Nay; **but we will have a king over us**;*

The rider on the white horse comes forth conquering and to conquer…..as that is what a king does.

> (20)  *That we also may be like all the nations; a**nd that our king may
>   judge us, and go out before us, and fight our battles**.*

They are not truly sent by the Lord to speak His words.  They are falsely sent (apostles = sent) even though they claim to come in His name (authority). They come in their own name and glory as though they are truly sent by the Lord.  They transform themselves into the ministers of righteousness but their end (destruction) shall be according to their works and they are leading MANY down with them in their destruction from off this earth.

> 2 Corinthians 11:12-15 KJV *(12)  But what I do, that I will do, that I
>   may cut off occasion from them which desire occasion; **that wherein
>   they glory, they may be found even as we**. (13)  F**or such are false
>   apostles, deceitful workers, transforming themselves into the apostles
>   of Christ.** (14)  And no marvel; for Satan himself is transformed into
>   an angel of light. (15)  Therefore it is no great thing if his
>   ministers **also be transformed as the ministers of righteousness; whose
>   end shall be according to their works**.*

These “natural brute beasts” are made to take (capture) and destroy (not made “to be taken and destroyed” but made TO take and destroy those who are unstable in doing His will).

That is their job:  to take and destroy those who are unstable in doing His will.   They do not have His Spirit but are sensual:  natural, brute beasts.

> 2 Peter 2:12-14 KJV (12)  ***But these, as natural brute beasts, made to
>   be taken and destroyed,*** speak evil of the things that they understand
>   not; and shall utterly perish in their own corruption; (13)  And shall
>   receive the reward of unrighteousness, as they that count it pleasure
>   to riot in the day time. Spots they are and blemishes, sporting
>   themselves with their own deceivings while they feast with you; (14) 
>   Having eyes full of adultery, and that cannot cease from sin;
>   **beguiling unstable souls:** an heart they have exercised with covetous
>   practices; cursed children:

They are used  as a means of judgment to destroy those who really do not believe (believing is DOING His will). They creep into our lives unawares...as men "sleep"...becoming forgetful in doing His will. They are ordained to condemnation and they are there to destroy those who fall "asleep" to doing His will.

> Jude 1:4-5 KJV (4)  For there are certain men crept in unawares, who
>   were before of old ordained to this condemnation, ungodly men, turning
>   the grace of our God into lasciviousness, and denying the only Lord
>   God, and our Lord Jesus Christ. (5)  **I will therefore put you in
>   remembrance, though ye once knew this, how that the Lord, having saved
>   the people out of the land of Egypt, afterward destroyed them that
>   believed not**.

A "natural, brute beast" is one that instinctively lies in wait to capture and devour its prey like a lion or a leopard does. That is their function in this current age....to capture and destroy (decay) those who waver in doing the will of God and they fall victim to the deceit that is found in their mouths and are led astray from the Way of righteousness that leads to His life being made manifest in their mortal flesh which would give them His eternal life in this earth.

Believing is doing.  We are not to become weary in well doing. Let us not "faint". In due season we shall reap His everlasting life in this earth.  We shall not perish from this earth but have everlasting life....the eternal life of Jesus in this earthen vessel.

> Galatians 6:9 KJV (9)  ***And let us not be weary in well doing:*** for in
>   due season we shall reap, **if we faint not**.

Those who become “feeble and weary” in doing well fall victim to those who come forth to deceive as they come forth and speak great swelling words of emptiness to those who are just escaping the pollutions of the world (Egypt) through the knowledge of the Lord and Savior Jesus Christ.

> 2 Peter 2:18-22 KJV (18)  F**or when they speak great swelling words of
>   vanity, they allure through the lusts of the flesh, through much
>   wantonness, those that were clean escaped from them who live in error.**
>   (19)  While they promise them liberty, they themselves are the
>   servants of corruption: for of whom a man is overcome, of the same is
>   he brought in bondage. (20)  **For if after they have escaped the
>   pollutions of the world through the knowledge of the Lord and Saviour
>   Jesus Christ,** they are again entangled therein, and overcome, the
>   latter end is worse with them than the beginning. (21)  **For it had
>   been better for them not to have known the way of righteousness**, than,
>   after they have known it, to turn from the holy commandment delivered
>   unto them. (22)  **But it is happened unto them** according to the true
>   proverb, The dog is turned to his own vomit again; and the sow that
>   was washed to her wallowing in the mire.

The “Amalek” (meaning “people who lick”….those who speak flattering things with the tongue...come forth just as we are escaping the pollutions of the world (Egypt).

> Deuteronomy 25:17-18 KJV (17)  **Remember what Amalek did unto thee by
>   the way, when ye were come forth out of Egypt;**

They meet us by the Way of righteousness (the Way of righteousness that we know we must be on).  If we become “feeble” …faint and weary in well doing, they will lead us astray and down the broad way that leads to destruction.

> (18)  ***How he met thee by the way, and smote the hindmost of thee, even
>   all that were feeble behind thee, when thou wast faint and weary; and
>   he feared not God.***

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the horse is the gospel. I believe it is the holy spirit. I also believe the rider to be a man, 1 man, whom the Lord has elected among all men. This man, will be given a crown of righteousness, a crown of victory. THE victory,  that is. I believe he will go out conquering (with peace?, some translations say that) and will be very Christ like. This man will be like a Shepard to the body of Christ, and will show them the way the truth and the life (he will be so much like Jesus, the way the truth and the life). I think this man, by the Lords will, will cause a great revival. There would be great praise to the Lord, blessings, and love through the body of Christ. And faith will be as strong as the apostles, for everyone who is with him. That's what I think and strongly believe. The man will share the gospel, but  more importantly will be living it. The Lords commands will be written on his heart. Some think he will be the next Elijah , as John the Baptist was.